# Is using @Transactional together with @Test annotation on the same test method a good practice?

Tags: java, unit-testing, object-oriented-design

In my current Java project, there is such style of integration test:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testBusinessTransaction() throws Exception {
    //...complicate set up code and execution code
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

**Question:**

- is using the `@Test` in combination with `@Transactional` suitable at all, esp. when set up code before the assertion is complicated?
- shouldn't the setup part of code, which forms the business transaction, be separated as another concern?
- transaction in the method is committed only when the method ends, then what this method is testing?